# How to get all available dimensions in Marketo API?

Tags: marketo

How can I get the list of all dimensions available to pass to the api to get data to construct the chart on the fly?

For example in this case, the dimension is Source:
http://www.marketo.com/_assets/uploads/ContentVideoTier/96/reports-analytics-roi.png?20131014201216

In google analytics, I can pass the dimensions available from the list here (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) via the api and it will give me the data that I can display in a chart.

How can I make similar behaviour in Marketo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of standard fields on a lead record in Marketo is [available here](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/faq/list-of-standard-fields/).

In addition to the standard fields, a Marketo user can add custom fields to their account. To get a list of all fields in a specific Marketo user's account, query the [Describe REST API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/describe/).

Lead activity data is also available through the Marketo API. To get a list of available activity types, query the [Get Activity Types REST API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-activity-types/).

Comment: Thanks Murtza.

I still can't figure out how to pass the field to the api. Which api should I use?
For example, I want to get the lead from 1 Jan - 15 Jan 2015 grouped by  leadSource using rest api.
Thanks.

Comment: First, query the Get Paging Token API with the sinceDateTime=2015-01-01 parameter, which will return a paging token needed to set the date bounds for the subsequent API call. 

Second, query the Get Lead Activities API with the paging token parameter and activityTypeIds=12 parameter. This second API call will return a list of new leads created in Marketo since January 1, 2015 including the lead source attribute.

Check out this blog post for more details:
http://developers.marketo.com/blog/get-activity-data-via-the-rest-api/

Comment: Thanks Murtza.
GetPagingToken API doesn't seem to support end date time. Is there a way to do that?

What is activityTypeIds=12 or activityTypeIds=24? Where can I get the reference of the available activity types?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct. The Get Paging Token API does not support an end date time. The activityTypeIds parameter is the way to specify what specific activity types are need when querying the Get Lead Activities API. The Get Activity Types API is a meta data API that returns a list of available activity types with their corresponding id (like id 12 for new leads created) and description of attributes that are returned for those ids (like lead source for id 12) : http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-activity-types/

Comment: Thanks Murtza. If there's no end date, how can I query for 1 Jan 2013 to 31 Jan 2013 data? Does a paging  token is only for a day, meaning that if I want to query data for 31 days, do I need to create 31 paging tokens? Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly. The paging token represents a cursor in the database. So the paging token does not represent an entire day, but just a specific point in time. This point in time is mapped to a location in the database. When you call Get Lead Activities API for the first time with the paging token from Get Paging Token API, it will return a new paging token in the response. This new paging token represents the current position of the cursor in the database, which would be at the end of the results set from the first call. You will then use this paging token to get the next set of results.

Comment: Mark, please let me know if the above explanation makes sense?

Comment: Thanks Murtza. I think I get the idea. So I need to call the api multiple times  until the results returned are beyond the expected end date. And there is no api for me to get the data aggregated weekly or monthly or quarterly, I have to calculate that manually. Is this correct?

Comment: Next is what to change if I want to get the lead number grouped by LeadSource or grouped by Program Channel as seen here: http://www.marketo.com/_assets/uploads/ContentVideoTier/188/ad-hoc-reports-analysis-screenshot.png?20131015040746?

Is it the &activityTypeIds (Lead Source - id=12 or Program Channel - id=?) parameter that I need to change? And I can get the id from querying the http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-activity-types/. Is it correct?
Thanks.

Comment: "So I need to call the api multiple times until the results returned are beyond the expected end date. And there is no api for me to get the data aggregated weekly or monthly or quarterly, I have to calculate that manually." Your understanding is correct. For your second question, the Get Activity Types API will return a schema of ids to activity types and their associated attributes. If you need leads by Lead Source, id 12 provides this data. If you needs leads by Program Channel, id 104 provides this data.

Comment: You can get the ID of get activity types but this list isn't the complete list, it's only the list of types that have been used already in activity in your instance. Is there a way to get the full list of possible activity_types? The list int he Marketo Documentation isn't complete